# string index out of range django

Tags: python, django

I am trying to iterate for an array but it throws the above error

here is the view:

```
brand_category = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')
for D in brand_category:
    print brand_category
    brands, categories = D[0] , D[1]
    print brands , categories
```

`brand_category` looks like this:

```
{"spykar":["Jeans","Sweater"],"Madame":["Tops","jeans"]}
```

here is the traceback:

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in view
  71.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py" in dispatch
  89.         return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\Grooved2\grooved\src\sellers\views.py" in post
  329.                      brands, categories = D[0] , D[1]
```

Comment: Where is the data coming from? `request.POST` cannot itself contain an element that is a dict.

Comment: `brand_category = self.request.POST.get('parameter[]')`  what is the type of brand_category? type(brand_category)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `brand_category` is not an array but a dictionary. If you do `for D in brand_category`, you were just looping through the keys. To loop the dictionary properly, do:

```
for brand, categories in brand_category.iteritems():
    print brand, categories
```

If you want to loop on the values which are lists, do:

```
for brand, categories in brand_category.iteritems():
    print brand
    for category in categories:
        print category
```

Comment: You might have the wrong variable then, `brand_category` is not a dictionary as you showed in the question, it's a `unicode` object. Check your code again.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's impossible because the error is SO obvious, you were using `iteritems()` function on a `unicode` object. Check python doc for more details: https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.iteritems. Maybe your `brand_category` is a json string that looks like a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

Iterating over a dict yields only keys. If you want to iterate over both keys and values then iterate over the result of the `iteritems()` method instead.